# JQuery each not giving expected number

Tags: jquery, html, each

When using a JQuery `.each` function i seem to be achieving a result i am confused by.

I am expecting the total to output the sum of all of the numbers within the `<span class='count'></span>`

But instead theres a number that appears but i cannot see why. The numbers in the span element appear to not be considered at all.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/H3t5L/)

**The HTML**

```
<span class='count'>1</span>
<span class='count'>2</span>
<span class='count'>3</span>
<button id='button'>Go</button>
<hr />

<span>Total: </span><span id='total'></span>
```

**The JQuery**

```
$("#button").click( function(total) {
    var total = 0;

    $('.count').each( function(total) {
        var content = $(this).text();
          //alert(content);
        num = parseInt(content);
         // alert(num);
        var newtotal = total + num;

         $('#total').html(total);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting 6 ?

```
$("#button").click( function(total) {
     var newtotal=0,total = 0;

    $('.count').each( function() {
        var content = $(this).text();
          //alert(content);
        num = parseInt(content);
         // alert(num);
         newtotal +=num;

         $('#total').html(newtotal);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/H3t5L/2/

Answer (score 1):

you're re-assigning the value of `total` with the index of `.each()`

change

```
$('.count').each( function(total) {
```

to

```
$('.count').each( function() {
```

Comment: where is the proof ?!